# When trying to use @RepositoryEventHandler annotatin I get 'Cannot resolve symbol 'RepositoryEventHandler' and the annotation is colored red

Tags: java, spring, annotations, event-handling

my problem is that when I'm trying to use @RepositoryEventHandeler annotation I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'RepositoryEventHandler'" information, as if Spring didn't recognize this annotation, I checked and it does not look like I need to add any dependencies for it to work. It's my first attempt at using it so maybe I got the whole idea behind it wrong. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Configuration class where I create a bean from class annotated with @RepositoryEventHandler

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationBeans {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler absenceRepositoryEventHandler() {
        return new AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface AbsenceRepository extends JpaRepository<Absence, Long> {
    List<Absence> findAbsencesByBarberId(Long barberId);

    List<Absence> findAbsencesByWorkDay_Id(Long workDayId);
}
```

Entity

```
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "absences")
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Absence {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    @JoinColumn(name = "barber_id")
    private Barber barber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "work_day_id")
    private WorkDay workDay;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "absence_start")
    private LocalTime absenceStart;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "absence_end")
    private LocalTime absenceEnd;
}
```

Class annotated with @RepositoryEventHandler (this annotation is all red and gives Cannot resolve symbol 'RepositoryEventHandle info)

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(Absence.class)
public class AbsenceRepositoryEventHandler {

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void handleAbsenceBeforeCreate(Absence absence){
    }
}
```

Controller class

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")

public class AbsenceController {

    private final AbsenceServiceImpl absenceService;
    private final AbsenceRepository absenceRepository;

    @GetMapping("/absences")
    public List<Absence> getAllAbsences() {
        return absenceRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/absencesById")
    public AbsenceDto getAbsencesById(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return absenceService.getAbsenceById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/absencesByBarber")
    public List<AbsenceDto> getAbsencesByBarber(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return absenceService.getAbsenceByBarber(id);
    }


    @GetMapping("/absencesByWorkDay")
    public List<AbsenceDto> getAbsencesByWorkDay(@RequestParam Long id) {
        return absenceService.getAbsenceByWorkDay(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/absence")
    public AbsenceDto createAbsence(@RequestBody @Valid CreateAbsenceDto absenceDto) {
        return absenceService.addAbsence(absenceDto);
    }


    @PutMapping("/update/absence/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateAbsence(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody @Valid AbsenceDto absence) {
        absenceService.updateAbsence(id, absence);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Absence was updated.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/delete/absence/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteAbsence(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        absenceService.removeAbsence(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Absence was deleted.", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Should've added dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now it works.